# Customize component URL

Tags: magento2, controllers, router

When creating a new component, the route depends completely on the directory structure, like so:

```
'module/controller/action'
```

Seems a little unnecessarily strict; can anyone point me to a means of mapping routes to shorter namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: we need to create a custom router.

- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/routing.html

We can take a look at Cms router module to see how it works.